# Logstash multiline codec doesn't work for stacktraces

Tags: logstash, stack-trace, multiline, elk

I'm using the ELK stack to process my app's logs. So, the problem is that Logstash multiline codec doesn't work properly for the stacktraces. The input multiline logs are not parsed by the pattern and are not merged with each other to be fully completed stacktrace.
Here is my configuration of multiline codec

```
    udp {
        port => 5140
        type => syslog
        codec => multiline {
            pattern => "^<%{NUMBER}>%{DATA} %{NUMBER} %{TIME} %{WORD}\[%{NUMBER}\]: \[%{TIMESTAMP_ISO8601}"
            negate => true
            what => "previous"
        }
    }
```

The ordinary logs look like this:

```
<27>Sep 19 17:47:37 worker[1819]: [2023-09-19 17:47:37,313: INFO/celery.app.trace] Task tasks.call_is_alive[call_is_alive_0ec30fbe-dde6-4a0e-b637-8eef926e28c8] succeeded in 0.2811723370105028s: None
```

And the stacktrace look like this:

```
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]: [2023-09-20 10:51:59,209: ERROR/uvicorn.error] Exception in ASGI application
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:     response = await self.dispatch_func(request, call_next)
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/base.py", line 69, in coro
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:     raise app_exc
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:     await self.app(scope, receive_or_disconnect, send_no_error)
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/cors.py", line 84, in __call__
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:     await self.app(scope, receive, send)
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 79, in __call__
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:     raise exc
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.11/site-packages/starlette/middleware/exceptions.py", line 68, in __call__
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]: Traceback (most recent call last):
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:                ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
<27>Sep 20 10:51:59 fastapi[1819]:     response = await call_next(request)
```

I've tried different patterns of multiline codec, but they also didn't helped. What can be the problem? Is it because of wrong pattern or something is wrong with the codec?